# Get auth token from URL

Tags: javascript, oauth

I am trying to get a Twitter oauth token using the below string. How can I "run" the string and then get the token?

**This is the request string:**

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=9TL0JGKTIv7GyOBeg8ynuxg&oauth_nonce=Xty48&oauth_signature=3skps99e6zkn0rcUGadVUEuHFon4%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1346603336
```

**This is the result:**

```
oauth_token=TBFdNoytaizrfMAWNZ6feqNz3BsozHk5AesIioX8u8Ec&oauth_token_secret=DtQ3jiUIeVdRcBAKwVQJRWpgKtEHi3m1ylk0nlsHCBj0&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript). It demonstrates how to get a value from the querystring.

Here, I've altered it to take the name value collection as a parameter:

```
function getParameterByName(name, qs)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(qs);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = "oauth_token=TBF...&oauth_token_secret=DtQ...";
var token = getParameterByName("oauth_token", result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only returns null unfortunately.

Comment: [Here's another](http://www.svlada.com/blog/2012/06/15/how-to-get-url-parameters-javascript/). There are loads if you Google it.